# Extending a CoffeeScript class dynamically

Tags: coffeescript

I know that a CoffeeScript class can be extended like this:

```
Dog::bark = ->
  console.log("bark")
```

I want to be able to do this dynamically. For example, I want to do something like this:

```
sounds = [ "bark", "woof", "grrr", "ruff" ] 

for sound in sounds
  Dog::[sound] = ->
    console.log(sound)
```

The equivalent JavaScript would be:

```
var sounds = [ "bark", "woof", "grrr", "ruff" ];

for (var i = 0; i < sounds.length; i++) 
{
  var sound = sounds[i];

  Dog.prototype[sound] = function() {
    console.log(sound);
  };
}
```

How can I do this with CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it, you just need to toss a `do` in there to force `sound` to be evaluated when you build the new method:

```
sounds = [ "bark", "woof", "grrr", "ruff" ] 
for sound in sounds
    do (sound) ->
        Dog::[sound] = -> console.log(sound)
```

If you don't include the `do` you'll end up with all four methods doing `console.log('ruff')`. Adding the `do` converts the `for` loop's body to a self-executing function. From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) (bottom of the section):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YAqJu/

Comment: Is `Dog::[sound]` really the correct syntax? I was just guessing.

Comment: @LandonSchropp: Yes it is. `::` is just `prototype` and `[sound]` is a normal object property reference. So `Dog::[sound]` is the same as `Dog.prototype[sound]` and that's what you want to add methods.

Comment: Nice catch on the closure wrapper as well. I wasn't even thinking about that.